# Finding the closest node

Tags: python, performance, recursion, graph

I have a function that I need to optimize:

```
def search(graph, node, maxdepth = 10, depth = 0):
    nodes = []
    for neighbor in graph.neighbors_iter(node):
        if graph.node[neighbor].get('station', False):
            return neighbor
        nodes.append(neighbor)
    for i in nodes:
        if depth+1 > maxdepth:
            return False
        if search(graph, i, maxdepth, depth+1):
            return i
   return False
```

`graph` should be a networkx graph object. How can I optimize this?  This should find the closest node in the network with `'station'` attribute to `True`.

Comment: You might have a bug: `if search(graph, i, ...): return i` ==> the search() function might return something other than i, yet you are returning i.

Comment: Not a bug, this should return the first step to the station.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def search(graph, node, maxdepth = 10, depth = 0):
    nodes = []
    for neighbor in graph.neighbors_iter(node):
        if graph.node[neighbor].get('station', False):
            return neighbor
        nodes.append(neighbor)
```

Why store the neighbor in the list? Instead of putting it in a list, just combine your two loops.

```
for i in nodes:
```

`i` typically stands for index. I suggest using neighbor to make your code easier to follow

```
    if depth+1 > maxdepth:
        return False
```

This doesn't relate to this individual node.  What is it doing inside this loop?

```
        if search(graph, i, maxdepth, depth+1):
            return i
   return False
```

Failure to find is better reported using `None` rather than `False`.

Comment: The first loop needs to be run on all litems and if none are station, it should search recursively

Comment: @fread2281, my bad... I didn't think of that. Actually, I think that makes your code wrong. Its implementing a DFS, so it wasn't neccesairlly find the closest "station"

Answer (score 4):

Is there any reason that you are shy from using networkx's functions such as breadth-first search `bfs_tree()` or depth-first search `dfs_tree()`? Here is an example of breadth-first search:

```
import networkx as nx
...
for visiting_node in nx.bfs_tree(graph, node):
    if graph.node[visiting_node].get('station', False):
        print 'Found it' # Do something with visiting_node
```

Comment: Good point, although it seems he couldn't do the max_depth with it...

Comment: I think max_depth is to prevent circular links in a graph. the `bfs_tree()` function ensures no circular references.

Comment: Ah, you may well be right.

Comment: `max_depth` is to limit time. I need speed.

Comment: I reimplemented it using a custom BFS and thanks for the indirect pointer!

Answer (score 2):

Are you implementing some routing protocol? Can you give me more details?

If your networking is based on equal weight (length) of each edges (let's say wired network or wireless network with backbone base station), than you can use breadth first search (fastest searching algorithm which takes \$O(|V|+|E|)\$ times).  If you want to find closest nodes base on geometry distance(it could be wireless networks or MANET ad-hoc network), than you need a greedy algorithm.

There are two ways to optimize your func:

- Searching algorithm: If you are looking for the
  shortest path or closest node in geometry distance, than you'd better to use greedy
  approach, BFS return shortest path only when edges have equal
  weight (cost, length, etc..). You probably know Dijkstra algorithm
  because it's widely used in network routings. So use a greedy
  algorithm would make your network links more stable and robust.
  You can choose [Best first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_first_search), [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_algorithm)(if
  you have information of target nodes).

  Although Breadth first search and depth first search are available to
  use in python, but they have some limitations: BFS tree is based on
  the entry of your neighbor list, it's won't guarantee to find
  shortest path (it's not a greedy algorithm). Same to DFS and your
  algorithm.
- choose a proper data structure to build your graph: A good data structure is always the easiest way to make your program faster. If you have more
  edges then vertexes (\$E > V^2\$) than use a neighbor matrix. Because
  in this scenario, if you are using a neighbor list,  it will take a
  considerable time to find out each edge whether belong to your
  graph or not.

  As a side effect, the memory overhead is huge for neighbor matrix.

Comment: My code should be a simple breadth first search.

Comment: average edges per vertex? are you using this for wired or wireless?